# How to hide this extra menu in IntelliJ Idea which contains the tasks that gradle ran?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I run some microservices, some of them have an additional menu in the RUN menu, which contains the tasks which was run.

Why do some services (projects) have this menu and some don't? How to hide this menu?

Gradle build tool is used everywhere.

[image]

Comment: Please vote for the related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219295

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this. It seems that it depends from how App is started from Intellij Idea.
If it is with Run/Debug Configurations - > Applications it shows the menu. When I changed the configuration to Spring Boot application it is not showing anymore..